# Get The Getters

Tags: code-golf, string, syntax

### The Task

I guess everybody loves automatic code generation and saving some time during work. You have to create a lot of classes and members during the day and you don't want to create all those `getters` manually.

The task is to write a program or function, that generates `getters` for all class members automatically for you.

---

### The Input

In our language objects are very simple. Names of classes and members must start with an chararacter from `[a-zA-Z]` and can only contain the characters `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Here's an example:

```
class Stack {
    public overflow;
    protected trace;
    private errorReport;
}
```

---

### The Output

This is a valid output based on the given example:

```
class Stack {
    public overflow;
    protected trace;
    private errorReport;

    public function getOverflow() {
        return this->overflow;
    }

    public function getTrace() {
        return this->trace;
    }

    public function getErrorReport() {
        return this->errorReport;
    }
}
```

---

### The Getter

The requirements for a `getter` method are:

- The function name must start with `get` followed by the member name with an uppercase initial.
- The function has no parameters.
- To return a variable use `return this->memberName;`.
- `getters` and `setters` (*see **The Bonuses***) must be grouped and must come after all variable declarations.

**Example:**

```
private value1;
private value2;

public function getValue1() { return this->value; }
public function setValue1(value) { this->value = value; }

public function getValue2() { return this->value; }
public function setValue2(value) { this->value = value; }
```

---

### The Requirements

- Create a program or a function.
- Input can come from STDIN, command line arguments, function arguments, a file etc.
- Any output format is acceptable from a simple `return`-value to a file or writing to STDOUT.
- In- and output don't need to be formatted with whitespaces, newlines, tabs etc. This is a valid input: `class A{protected a;}`.
- You can assume that the input is valid and your program can handle unexpected input unexpected as well.

---

### The Bonuses

You can get down to 10% of your original byte count by withdrawing 30% for each feature:

**A:** Your program can address newly added variables and adds missing `getters` only (`public function getB() { return this->b; }` in this case):

```
class A {
    public a;
    public b;

    public function getA() { return this->a; }
}
```

**B:** Your program also generates `setters`:

```
class A {
    public a;
    public getA() { return this->a; }
    public setA(a) { this->a = a; }
}
```

**C:** Your program can handle static members:

```
class A {
    public static c;
    public static function getC() { return this->c; }
}
```

---

This is code golf – so shortest answer in bytes wins. Standard loopholes are disallowed.

Comment: This is my first question - a not too hard one. Hope you like it. Thanks to [Martin Büttner](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-büttner) for helpful tips in the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/41859).

Comment: Will there only be one class per input?

Comment: If the input has no newlines, should the output have any?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes, there will be only one class per input.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Newlines are optional. The output can be pretty or minified.

Comment: When supporting both bonuses `A` and `B` should items that have getters, but no setters, have setters in the output?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That's a very good question. I would say that for bonus **B** you can assume that the input is complete, so if there's a getter there's also a setter.

Comment: Do the setters always have to take a variable of that name? For instance, would it be valid to generate `public function setOverflow(x){this->overflow=x;}`?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Yes that would be valid, as it doesn't break functionality.

Comment: In which language are you allowed to refer to `this` in a `static` accessor?

Comment: @Neil Good catch - I thought nobody would notice. I saw my mistake  after I posted it and there was already one answer. So I didn't want to change the requirements afterwards. It's a very special language. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Perl, 161 - 90% = 16.1 bytes

```
$/=0;$_=<>;for$g(/\bp\S*( +static)? +(\S*);/g){++$i%2?$c="public$g function":/get\u$g/||s/}$/$c get\u$g(){return this->$g;}\n$c set\u$g(x){this->$g=x;}\n}/}print
```

Comment: You beat the Pyth answer o_o kudos!

Answer (score 10):

## Pyth, <s>198 bytes - 90% = 19.8 bytes</s> <s>187 - 90% = 18.7 bytes</s> 183 bytes - 90% = 18.3 bytes

```
pJ<rs.z6_1sm?}+=b"get"K+rh=Zed1tZJks[Y=N|@d1kGbK"(){return "=H+"this->"Z";}"YNG"set"K"(x){"H"=x;}"):Js["(?:(?:"=Y"public""|private|protected)(?!"=G" function "")( static)?) (\w+)")4\}
```

*Must...beat...Perl...*

### 187-byte/18.7-byte version

```
J<rs.z6_1s_+\},sm?}+=b"get"K+rh=Zed1tZJks[Y=N|@d1kGbK"(){return "=H+"this->"Z";}"YNG"set"K"(x){"H"=x;}"):Js["(?:(?:"=Y"public""|private|protected)(?!"=G" function "")( static)?) (\w+)")4J
```

### 198-byte/19.8-byte version

```
J<rs.z6_1s_,sm?}K+rhed1tedJks["public"=N|@d1k=G" function ""get"K"(){return this->"ed";}public"NG"set"K"("ed"){this->"ed"="ed";}"):J"(?:(?:public|private|protected)(?! function )( static)?) (\w+)"4J
```

**TODO:** More golfing!

Comment: +1 for Must beat pearl...

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript ES6 (at the moment), <s>305</s> <s>289</s> 223 - 60% = 89.2 bytes

Was `256 - 30% = 179.2 bytes`

Qualifies for static and setter bonuses; now with extra ES6!

```
s=>s.replace(/\}$/,s.match(/(public|private)( static)* \w+/g).map(e=>{o=(r=e.split` `).pop();return(n=r.join` `)+` get${U=o[0].toUpperCase()+o.slice(1)}(){return this->${o};}${n} set${U}(${o}){this->${o}=${o};}`}).join``+"}")
```

### ES5 function, 115.6 bytes

```
function g(s){return s.replace(/\}$/,s.match(/(p(?:ublic|rivate))( static)* (\w+?);/gm).map(function(e){o=(r=e.split(" ")).pop().replace(/;/,"");return(n=r.join(" "))+" get"+(U=o[0].toUpperCase()+o.slice(1))+"(){return this->"+o+";}"+n+" set"+U+"("+o+"){this->"+o+"="+o+";}"}).join("")+"}")}
```

Comment: I think `o.slice(1,o.length))` can simply be shortened to `o.slice(1))`, and I think you can inline `v`, since you only use it once (i.e., start your function with `return s.replace(/\}$/, s.match(...).map...`). Also, I don't believe you need a space between `return` and `(`.

Comment: @apsillers  Good point. I was going to do the second suggestion, but I simply had no time. Thanks for your golfs! ^_^

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes just having `public|private` in your regex!

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 71 bytes

```
q';/W<_{S%W=:O(eu"public function get"\@"{return this->"O";}"}%\';f+\'}
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q'%3B%2FW%3C_%7BS%25W%3D%3AO(eu%22public%20function%20get%22%5C%40%22%7Breturn%20this-%3E%22O%22%3B%7D%22%7D%25%5C'%3Bf%2B%5C'%7D&input=class%20A%7Bprotected%20a%3B%7D).